# Keeping timezone when saving datetime in dataframe as csv

Tags: python, pandas, time, pytz

I am using the following code to save a timestamp to disk and then find how much time has elapsed since that time at a later date. My problem is that when I use the businesstimedelta package, it returns an error that my dataframe has no timezone. I am assuming that it is lost when saved to csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
import pytz
import businesstimedelta
from pytz import timezone   


workday = businesstimedelta.WorkDayRule(start_time=datetime.time(9,30),end_time=datetime.time(16),working_days=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

timestamps = pd.DataFrame([datetime.datetime.now(timezone('America/New_York'))])
time.sleep(5)
timestamps.to_csv('timestamps.csv')
timestamps2 = pd.read_csv('timestamps.csv')
difference = workday.difference(timestamps2,datetime.datetime.now(timezone('America/New_York'))).hours
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-0e7502d68c65> in <module>
     10 timestamps.to_csv('timestamps.csv')
     11 timestamps2 = pd.read_csv('production temp/positions.csv')
---> 12 difference = workday.difference(timestamps2,datetime.datetime.now(timezone('America/New_York'))).hours

c:\users\g\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\businesstimedelta\rules\rule.py in difference(self, dt1, dt2)
     29     def difference(self, dt1, dt2):
     30         """Calculate the business time between two datetime objects."""
---> 31         dt1 = localize_unlocalized_dt(dt1)
     32         dt2 = localize_unlocalized_dt(dt2)
     33         start_dt, end_dt = sorted([dt1, dt2])

c:\users\g\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\businesstimedelta\businesstimedelta.py in localize_unlocalized_dt(dt)
      8     https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone
      9     """
---> 10     if dt.tzinfo is not None and dt.tzinfo.utcoffset(dt) is not None:
     11         return dt
     12     return pytz.utc.localize(dt)

c:\users\g\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5463             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5464                 return self[name]
-> 5465             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5466 
   5467     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

Comment: Can you take a close look at the code snippet you provided? The `timestamps2` is not used

Comment: i've edited it, that was a mistake when I typed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming that it is lost when saved to csv

Yes, this is part of your problem. CSV is a low-fidelity data format that does not preserve the data types of most objects. Everything is read as a number or string at first. It is then the responsibility of the reader of the CSV to figure out what data types to use. (Pandas does a decent job detecting automatically.)

You have several options here:

1. Convert the string to the right datetime format after you read in the dataframe.

```
timestamps2["0"] = pd.to_datetime(timestamps2["0"])
```

2. Tell Pandas exactly what converter to use when it reads the file.

```
timestamps2 = pd.read_csv("./timestamps.csv", converters={"0": pd.to_datetime})
```

3. Export to a different file format that preserves your data types, such as pickle.

Now, once you have read your data and loaded it to datetime data types rather than `object`, you will find that the series has dtype `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`:

```
dt1 = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('America/New_York'))
timestamps = pd.Series(data=[dt1])
print(type(dt1)) # <class 'datetime.datetime'>
print(timestamps.dtype) # datetime64[ns, America/New_York]
print(type(timestamps.at[0])) # <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

It doesn't seem like the `businesstimedelta` library offers vectorized operations on Pandas objects, and it only appears to work on native Python datetime objects. So here is one solution:

```
dt1 = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('America/New_York'))
dt2 = dt1 + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
timestamps = pd.Series([dt1])
timestamps.apply(lambda dt: workday.difference(dt.to_pydatetime(), dt2))
```

```
0    <BusinessTimeDelta 0 hours 1 seconds>
dtype: object
```

You should also look into Pandas' native support for time deltas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html

And a variety of support for business days: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html?highlight=business#dateoffset-objects

Comment: OK Thanks. I checked out the native Pandas time deltas, but it doesn't seem to be able to handle business hours, or have I missed something?

Comment: see my update about converting your series back to native datetime